# Notice: Undefined index: file when uploading file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to do a file check in an MVC framework, and even if I put the file with a jpg format, I am getting `error`

This is the function that checks the format

```
public function addAction()
{
     $upload = new Upload();
     if($this->request->isPost())
     {
        $allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(!in_array($ext,$allowed))
        {
          echo 'error';
        }
        $this->request->csrfCheck();
        $upload->assign($this->request->get());
        $upload->user_id = Users::currentUser()->id;
        if($upload->save())
        {
           Router::redirect('upload');
        }
    }
    $this->view->uploas = $upload ;
    $this->view->displayErrors = $upload->getErrorMessages();
    $this->view->postAction = PROOT . 'upload' . DS . 'add';
    $this->view->render('upload/add');
}
```

And this is the HTML code:

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 upload-position center" >
     <input type="file" id="file" name="file" >
 </div>
```

The `isPost` method checks if the form method is post

Comment: Did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form attributes?

Comment: @Pilan taht were the error , thanks ,you add it as a reply if you want the rep

Comment: Better to check the (real) mime type than trusting the extension alone.

Comment: @dnFer i have separate method that checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next one looking for it :)

To upload a file you will need `enctype="multipart/form-data"`:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
</form>
```